# How to display data in data table in textbox? vb.net

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

Good day. I am trying to display data from data table to text box control. But when the program run, I wasn't able to press the calculate button. Before this i've tried  to display the data on datagridview control and it displayed. Is there anyone that could help me? Very much appreciated.

```
    provider = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source ="
    dataFile = "C:\Users\User\Documents\SharkRay Database.accdb"
    connString = provider & dataFile
    myConnection.ConnectionString = connString
    myConnection.Open()

    Dim da As OleDbDataAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter("Select Sum([Shark Individual Weight]) From FishCaught Where [OperationID] =" & TextBoxOpID4.Text & " and [Scientific Name] ='" & ComboBoxSpeciesName2.SelectedItem & "'", myConnection)

    Dim ds As DataTable = New DataTable()
    da.Fill(ds)

    TextBoxAllSharkTW.Text = ds.ToString()

    myConnection.Close()
```

Comment: common men every problem needs to post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand("Select Sum([Shark Individual Weight]) From    FishCaught Where [OperationID] =" & TextBoxOpID4.Text & " and [Scientific Name] ='" & ComboBoxSpeciesName2.SelectedItem & "'", myConnection)
    Dim count As Integer = cmd.ExecuteScalar()

    TextBoxSharkTWbySpecies.Text = count.ToString()
    cmd.Dispose()
    myConnection.Close()
```

I did a little amendment to the code given by Shadow Fiend and finally it works! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
 provider = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source ="
    dataFile = "C:\Users\User\Documents\SharkRay Database.accdb"
    connString = provider & dataFile
    myConnection.ConnectionString = connString
    myConnection.Open()

               Dim cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand("Select Sum([Shark Individual Weight]) From FishCaught Where [OperationID] =" & TextBoxOpID4.Text & " and [Scientific Name] ='" & ComboBoxSpeciesName2.SelectedItem & "'", myConnection)
        Dim count As Int32 = CInt(cmd.ExecuteScalar)

        TextBoxAllSharkTW.Text = cstr(count)
 myConnection.Close()
```

Comment: @lee what happen?

Comment: still cannot press the button

Comment: what?! cannot press the button? what do u mean

Comment: The code above is in this  Private Sub ButtonCalcTWbySpecies_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ButtonCalcTWbySpecies.Click. What i mean is i cannot click the button when using the code you give me.